# evaluating/parsing javascript from a programatically downloaded webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, parsing, html, evaluate

I was wondering if there was some type of library (preferably for .NET) that allows a web page downloaded (for instance, using HttpWebResponse) that can evaluate javascript variables and evaluate and parse javascript procedures.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Awesomium](http://princeofcode.com/awesomium.php).  .NET + webkit (chrome rendering engine).  From the website:

> **Javascript Integration**
>   Execute
>   arbitrary Javascript, invoke C++
>   callbacks from Javascript, pass
>   arrays, objects, and other types
>   to/from a page, and more!

---

Sorry, its not specifically WPF.  [Chris Cavanagh](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/wpf-chromium-webbrowser-source-code/) ported it, but you can use awesomium from your .net code.

Comment: The website is pretty awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

[Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com) is an open-source Javascript interpreter for .NET. You can run Javascript code within your application, and exchange object for doing automation for instance.

You can even define a DHTML object model and pass it as an argument if you want to simulate a browser.

Answer (score 0):

It will require some work, but it should be possible to accomplished using [ECMAScript.NET](http://code.google.com/p/ecmascript-net/).